# Is there mmseg in Go or can I call a self-defined C function from Go?

Tags: c, nlp, go

I want to use mmseg in Go as in other languages, for example, in python you can use pymmseg

So, is there is a similar Go package?

Or, how can I call the C functions from Go?
Or, how can I call shared library (*.so) from Go like in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call use C Libs as described in this tutorial:

http://cheesesun.blogspot.de/2009/12/basic-cgo.html

and:

http://siganakis.com/linking-c-libraries-with-go-lang-and-stdc99

or you may have a look at this library:

https://github.com/awsong/MMSEGO

its for chinese, but you may could use it to put your own algorithm there.

Comment: the MMSEGO's example can not run

Comment: what means, can not run ? you got compile error ? or is something missing ? maybe you also need go-darts: https://github.com/awsong/go-darts

Comment: The origin function is too complict. I rewrite the function @ `https://github.com/Codefor/MMSEGO/blob/darts/mmsego.go`